# Iterate through the json object ignoring first object

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i m trying to iterate the objects using object.keys where i want to ignore the first object and loop through the remaining items or obejcts

below is the object structure:

```
controls = {
  101: {
    value: true
  },
  131: {
    value: false
  },
  134: {
    value: false
  },
  136: {
    value: false
  },
  123: {
    value: false
  },
}
```

here is the code which i am trying to loop and get final result:

```
const value = Object.keys(controls).forEach((k, i) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    return controls[k].value === false;
  }
})
console.log(value, 'result')
```

The output should be: -

value should return true -->  if all the value are false else return true if one of the object is true, except the first value i.e is id: 101

Comment: Numeric properties are reordered and the property that is defined first does not necessarily end up being at the first position.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the first ? I ask, because if its to filter the `true` values, there's an easier way of doing that.

Comment: Your implementation has a lot of mistakes, including syntax and typos. What is controls in second snippet? Why use a snippet if it's not gonna work? First element of foreach callback is a value not an index, return statements of forEach callback are ignored, to top it all of the order of keys of objects is not guaranteed so "first property" doesnt mean anything

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski The `controls` is just the object, what does it matter what it is?  The ignored return in the forEach  and using `k` as index are the problems OP is having.

Comment: @Baruch i want to ignore first because the first one i am using to display in the table as first column, so if first row of value of first column is checked then remaining should get checked, that the purpose. So to get the value i want to ignore the value of first objectand consider the second to n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on implementation order of keys of objects may not be guaranteed so you should be extra careful with it. Assuming that order is what you want it to be, you could use `slice` and `every` or `some` array methods.

```js
const obj = {
  101: {
    value: true
  },
  131: {
    value: false
  },
  134: {
    value: false
  },
  136: {
    value: false
  },
  123: {
    value: false
  },
}

const result = !Object.values(obj).slice(1).every(({value}) => !value);
const result2 = Object.values(obj).slice(1).some(({value}) => value);

console.log({result, result2})
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: this is giving me result of each obejct but i need the result  if all the objects are false then return as false else if even one of the object is true return true, but should ignore the first object value

Comment: The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function, (test being `!value`). It does exactly what you asked for

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, try something like this:

```js
let obj = {
          101: {
            value: true
          },
          131: {
            value: false
          },
          134: {
            value: false
          },
          136: {
            value: false
          },
          123: {
            value: false
          },
        }
        let result = false;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((k, i) => {
           if (k !== "101") result = result || obj[k].value;
        })
        console.log(result)
```

A forEach on all keys and a bool `result` in which store `value` values.

Comment: Why would you use `forEach` for this, this use case is not what it is for.

Comment: Ciao, correct. It was just for iterate in all values of the object. But conceptually you are right.

Comment: this is giving me result of each obejct but i need the result if all the objects are false then return as false else if even one of the object is true return true, but should ignore the first object value

Comment: It's just necessary to replace `&&` with `||` and skip first element. If all value are false then the || returns false. Otherwise returns true.